# Logical operators in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide, logical-operators

I need to check value of an attribute in Selenium IDE. But the value can be "ABC" or "XYZ" randomly.
How to use OR operator to check if the value is valid?

I tried **glob** with **|** character, but it does not work:

verifyAttribute | xpath=.//*[@id='content']/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]@href | glob:(*ABC*)|(*XYZ*)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

```
verifyText | your ID here | regex:[ABC]|[XYZ]

<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>your ID here</td>
    <td>regex:[ABC]|[XYZ]</td>
</tr>
```

This will match either ABC or XYZ exactly